# Is there any way to easily make statistics by ten days using DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

The `semiMonthBegin(X, [dayOfMonth=15], [offset], [n=1])` function works fine with the default `dayOfMonth=15` day cycle. However, if I want to calculate on ten-day basis and set `dayOfMonth=10`, the result is wrong.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`semiMonthBegin` is not suitable for ten-day-based calculation. You can use a user-defined function with a `group by` clause. For example:

```
def f(x) {
    Count = x.size()
    res = array(STRING, Count)
    for (i in 0:Count){
        if(int(x[i].format("dd"))<=10){
            res[i] = x[i].format("yyyy.MM.")+"10"
        }
        else if(int(x[i].format("dd")) <=20){
            res[i] = monthEnd(x[i]).format("yyy.MM.dd")
        }
    return res
}
t1 = select *, date(f(date)) as xun from t1
select avg(price), sum(qty) from t1 group by xun;
```

You can also use `dayOfMonth` function to calculate by any day.

```
select *, date-(dayofMonth(date)-1)%10 as xun from t1
```